# how to get product details from amazon by searching for this product URL at my website?

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-product-api

i am brand new to amazon api and i am trying to grab product details from amazon by putting this product URL in my website search input and then find this product details within my website. i have found a solution to search for products within my website and this is not useful for me. i wanna put the product link and find it's details.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the Amazon Product Service API. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html.

Comment: well i need to request an item by it's URL

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use the amazon api

Answer (score 1):

you will need to extract the ASIN number from the URL then use Amazon Product Service API to LookupItem() or any other method fetch the details of the product.

to do that, amazon associate account, and aws developer account must be created.

good luck